# Drupal, Displaying a Content list of a User from their Profile, accessible by anyone via Views

Tags: views

I am running Drupal 7 and I would like to know how to create a View that displays as a tab on a users profile that displays all of his or her created content. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP3Ui.png) is what I have so far, but it only shows the tab for the logged in user, no one else can access it.

I got most of the code from [here.](https://drupal.org/node/1108312)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you were very close.  I would add on to the contextual filter.  You need to provide a default value for the filter.  Either of the following will work:

- Using PHP Code.  Enter the following into the box "return arg(1);" without the quotes.
- Raw value from URL.  Change Path component to 2.

Comment: Either of those don't work when I access another user's profile, I don't see the "My Content" tab. It may be useful if I told you the path to the user is such example.com/user/*username*

Comment: Also, If I change the validation criteria off, still nothing happens.